# Regex extracting proper Hearst pattern

Tags: regex, nltk, python-re

I tried to extract Hearst Patterns by using regex. I tried to encompass "JJs" and "VBGs" in the NPs as well. For example NP_first_executive_budget not just NP_budget. I am using the following pattern and code and example :

```
text = ["eliot spitzer will preview his first executive budget in a speech on friday afternoon , laying out his plan to rein in medicaid and other health care spending , setting the stage for a battle with politically powerful health care providers and unions .","galloway 's account is among about 150 new complaints that have emerged from 44 secure state schools , halfway houses and residential youth care programs in texas as a result of several overlapping inquiries into accusations of sexual abuse and other mistreatment there ."]

annotated = ["NP_eliot_spitzer  will  preview  his  NP_first_executive_budget  in  a  NP_speech  on  NP_friday_afternoon ,  NP_laying  out  his  NP_plan  to  rein  in  NP_medicaid  and  other  NP_health_care_spending ,  NP_setting  the  NP_stage  for  a  NP_battle  with  politically  NP_powerful_health_care_providers  and  NP_unions .","NP_galloway 's  NP_account  is  among  about  150  NP_new_complaints  that  have  emerged  from  44  NP_secure_state_schools ,  NP_halfway_houses  and  NP_residential_youth_care_programs  in  NP_texas  as  a  NP_result  of  NP_several__overlapping_inquiries  into  NP_accusations  of  NP_sexual_abuse  and  other  NP_mistreatment  there "]
```

`p  = r'NP_[\w.]*(?:\s*(?:,|\bor\b|,?\s*and(?:\s+other)?\b)\s*NP_[\w.]*)+'`

```
 for match in re.findall(p, annotated):
        matches=[]
        matches.extend(re.findall(r'NP_[\w.]*\b', match))
        matches = [w.replace('NP_', '').replace('_', ' ') for w in matches]
        if matches:
            print(matches)
```

The pattern extracts multiple outputs.

Example 1

```
['friday afternoon', 'laying']
['medicaid', 'health care spending', 'setting']
['powerful health care providers', 'unions']
```

Example 2

```
['secure state schools', 'halfway houses', 'residential youth care programs']
['sexual abuse', 'mistreatment']
```

I want it to extract only the `and other` patterns such as `medicaid and other health care spending`  and the in second example `sexual abuse and other mistreatment` and ignore the rest. I tried to tweak the pattern `p` but so far its extracting all the other things as well. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What is a Hearst pattern?

Comment: So Hearst patterns are basically hyponym- hypernym relationship. For example the use of "such as" , "and other", "including" etc where hyponyms are the entities or specific terms and hypernym is the general or aggregated term. An example would be : Fruits such as  apples, oranges and grapes.